# What is the difference between the Pycharm Virtual Environment and the Existing Intrepreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, environment

I'm quite new to programming using PyCharm. The problem that I'm facing is that when I want to create a new project, I'm prompted with two options for the project interpreter. My question is that is there any **differences between the Virtual Environment option and the Existing Interpreter option**? And if there are any differences, is there any way to **switch between the different option for projects that I have already created**?

Answer (score 0):

`Existing interpreter` means an interpreter that has been already used in PyCharm.
First option suggests you to create a new environment for a new project.

The interpreter used in a project could be changed at any time after.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-empty-project.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.

Comment: If the interpreter could be changed, how can I do it?

Comment: @SK21 `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter` or via status bar widget in the right corner